# Error "Resource Not Found" creating Cosmos DB container with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I am running the following command to create a container for my Cosmos DB, that I copied from the manual and replaced with my account values.

```
az cosmosdb sql container create -g pluralSight -a pluralsightgreetingbot -d greetingbot -n messages --partition-key-path "/messages"
```

Error says "Resource not found". I double checked my inputs and all seem to be OK.

[image]

This is the complete error as output:

```
Command group 'cosmosdb sql' is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 13db110d-62e6-4a8e-93f9-27c6fbcde5e9. Message: {"code":"NotFound","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource Not Found\"]}\r\nActivityId: b8e95cb7-0f13-11ea-a134-f4f26d19196a, Request URI: /apps/d56d4719-881c-450a-8a93-f55ae16f5b41/services/01ec4f79-1a4b-4571-8706-a9d9e210e4db/partitions/fff88e8a-d1bf-4dc0-812f-cc8c8b985b82/replicas/132188457808536080s, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-11-24T23:40:02.0661568Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-11-24T23:40:02.0661568Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2019-11-24T23:40:02.0661568Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.26:11300/apps/d56d4719-881c-450a-8a93-f55ae16f5b41/services/01ec4f79-1a4b-4571-8706-a9d9e210e4db/partitions/fff88e8a-d1bf-4dc0-812f-cc8c8b985b82/replicas/132188457808536080s, LSN: 3, GlobalCommittedLsn: 3, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#3, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Database, OperationType: Read\r\nResponseTime: 2019-11-24T23:40:02.0661568Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.24:11000/apps/d56d4719-881c-450a-8a93-f55ae16f5b41/services/01ec4f79-1a4b-4571-8706-a9d9e210e4db/partitions/fff88e8a-d1bf-4dc0-812f-cc8c8b985b82/replicas/132189292853257376s, LSN: 3, GlobalCommittedLsn: 3, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#3, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Database, OperationType: Read\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0"}, Request URI: /dbs/MyDatabase/colls, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your database resource first, separately. Collection-creation doesn't create the database at the same time. Pretty sure the "resource not found" is the database that still needs to be created.

This is done with a similar `az` command. In your case, something like:

```
az cosmosdb sql database create -a pluralsightgreetingbot -g pluralSight -n greetingbot --throughput 400
```

Comment: if you read through the error carefully you will notice the following: `ResourceType: Database`, so your assumption is probably correct.